# read files in folder

Tags: php, file

In my application there is a folder name videos. i want to raed all file only of this folder  I have done almostly it does not show any folder in folder videos except .DS_Store
currently i have applied if condition to hide this but i want a perfect solution can any one help:-  my code is :----

```
$dir = "../videos/";
$dh  = opendir($dir);

print '<select size="4" name="vidfile">';

while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

    if (is_file($dir.'/'.$file) && $file != "." && $file != "..") {

        if ($file!=".DS_Store") {

            print "<option>{$file}</option>";
        }
    }          
}

print '</select>'; 

closedir($dh);
```

Answer (score 13):

**The quick and easy solution**

You could make your life easier and use a [`DirectoryIterator`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) to go over the directory.

```
echo '<select name="vids" size="4">';
foreach( new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/videos') as $file) {
    if( $file->isFile() === TRUE && $file->getBasename() !== '.DS_Store') {
        printf("<option>%s</option>\n", htmlentities($file->getBasename()));
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

---

**Improvement: Decoupling Directory Filtering from SelectBox building**

If you want to decouple the filtering logic from the `foreach` loop, you can subclass a `FilterIterator` to capsule that logic into it's `accept()` method. The `DirectoryIterator` has to be wrapped into the `FilterIterator` then. The main point is reusability of course:

```
class MyFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    public function accept()
    {
        return $this->current()->isFile() === TRUE &&
               $this->current()->getBasename() !== '.DS_Store';
    }
}

$iterator = new MyFilter(new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/videos'));
```

When you use `foreach` on a filtered iterator, it will trigger `accept()` automatically. If `accept()` returns `FALSE`, the current element will be filtered out in the iteration.

You create the SelectBox like this then:

```
echo '<select name="vids" size="4">';
foreach( $iterator as $file) {
    printf("<option>%s</option>\n", htmlentities($file->getBasename()));
}
echo '</select>';
```

---

**Alternative to subclassing FilterIterator**

If you are too lazy to write a separate `FilterIterator` or think it's just not worth it for a specific case or already have validators somewhere and dont want to duplicate their code, but still want to decouple Filtering and SelectBox creation, you can also use this custom [`FilterChainIterator`](http://github.com/salathe/spl-examples/wiki/FilterChain-Iterator) and add callbacks to it:

```
$iterator = new FilterChainIterator(new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/videos'));
$iterator->addCallback(function($file) {
    return $file->isFile() === TRUE &&
           $file->getBasename() !== '.DS_Store';});
```

The SelectBox creation would be the same as shown above.

---

**Improvement: Making SelectBox creation reusable**

In addition, if you want to make the SelectBox creation reusable, why not create a Helper for it. Below is a very simple one that uses DOM to create the actual HTML. You pass in any Iterator and it will create the HTML for you when you call it's `render()` method or use it in a string context:

```
class SelectBox
{
    protected $iterator;
    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator)
    {
        $this->iterator = $iterator;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
        $dom->loadXml('<select name="vids"/>');
        $dom->documentElement->appendChild(new DOMElement('option', 'Pick One'));
        foreach($this->iterator as $option) {
            $dom->documentElement->appendChild(
                new DOMElement('option', $option));
        }
        return $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement);
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->render();
    }
}
```

And then printing a SelectBox from an Iterator is as simple as

```
echo new SelectBox(new MyFilter(new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/videos')));
```

That's pretty flexible then, given that there is Iterators for everything. For instance

```
echo new SelectBox(new ArrayIterator(array('foo', 'bar', 'baz')));
```

would give a neatly formatted

```
<select>
  <option>Pick One</option>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>baz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why the identical (===) operator in `$file->isFile() === TRUE`? I'd imagine that just `$file->isFile()` would work the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$dir = '../videos/';
if($dh = opendir($dir)){
   echo '<select size="4" name="vidfile">';
   while(($file=readdir($dh)) !== FALSE){
      $file = $dir . '/' . $file;
      if(!is_file($file) || substr($file, 0, 1) == '.'){
         continue;
      }
      printf('<option>%s</option>', htmlentities($file));
   }
   echo '</select>';
   closedir($dh);
}
?>
```

First, if opendir fails, don't continue with junk. It ignores non-files (directories) and files starting with a dot (including ., .., .htaccess, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation that works with [`glob()`](http://www.php.net/glob) instead, has an array of excluded files, and collects all the `option` elements and then outputs them as one. Also, `glob()` allows filtering for certain file extensions through its brace syntax as shown in the out-commented line.

```
$dir = "../videos";
$mask = "*";
// $mask = "*.{wmv,mpeg,mpg}";  // get only files of these types

$files = glob($dir."/".$mask);
$excluded_files = array(".DS_store");
$html = null;    

if (count($files) > 0)
foreach ($files as $file)
 {
  $filename = basename($file);
  if (in_array($filename, $excluded_files)) continue;
  $html.="<option>".htmlentities($filename)."</option>";
 }

 echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `if ($file[0] == ".") continue;` instead of these 2 if's is probably what you're looking for.
Though I'd make it slightly different, in 2 parts.
getting data part:

```
<?php
  $dir = "../videos/";
  $dh = opendir($dir);
  $filesarr = array();
  while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if ($file[0] != ".") $filesarr[] = $file;
  }
  closedir($dh);
?>
```

and display data part:

```
<select size="4" name="vidfile">
<?php foreach ($filesarr as $file): ?>
<option><?php echo $file ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

it seems way more clean to me